# How can I check that files match a list of MD5 checksums on Android?

Tags: android-13, samsung-galaxy-s-23, checksum

I downloaded a large number of files via `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5f96d43576e3d386c9ba65b883210a393b68210e&tr=https%3A%2F%2Facademictorrents.com%2Fannounce.php&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce` (Apache 2.0 license) and [LibreTorrent](https://github.com/proninyaroslav/libretorrent) (GPL-3.0 license).

A file lists MD5 checksums:

```
ea5774684fe8af0c8dbc73f0587b3ed3  ./tensor00251_000
5e5ac7153ade3bc0258ea8909b411aef  ./tensor00084_000
6358c62cef61d79c24fd223b21798b49  ./tensor00093_000
13f15b98afecc281d84801acf347e220  ./tensor00442_000
392f867c92b96f8c8c7214190f853f2c  ./tensor00277_000
6f5a97ddc80c8d5207d4d165d53121c6  ./tensor00072_000
d6b4317b176fcd0054a70a3a8675daf5  ./tensor00609_000
fceacb314134d5d0218df727954a8596  ./tensor00119_000
```

This list is chopped but it contains 770 lines (i.e., 770 MD5 checksums), so I'd like to batch check them. I know how to compute a MD5 checksum on a single file, but I don't know how to check all these files at once.

How can I check that the downloaded files match these MD5 checksums on Android?

I use a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13.

Comment: Write a script in [Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) assuming that Termux can access the checksum list file and the files themselves. Just be aware of Android 12+ issues: https://github.com/termux/termux-app